# Errors with discord.py Polling Command

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I want to basically make a poll command that takes the emojis a user puts in and uses it as a reaction but I also want to make it so there are multiple emojis allowed to be used so if there were to be more than 2 options it would work with this command.

Example:
!poll test :white_large_square: :black_large_square: :tired_face:

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: poll() missing 2 required keyword-only arguments: 'em1' and 'em2'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: poll() missing 2 required keyword-only arguments: 'em1' and 'em2'
```

Code:

````
async def poll(ctx, *, message, em1, em2, em3=None, em4=None, em5=None, em6=None, em7=None, em8=None, em9=None, em10=None):
    authorperms = ctx.author.permissions_in(ctx.channel)
    if authorperms.manage_messages:
        emb = discord.Embed(title="Poll", color=discord.Color.red())
        emb.add_field(name="Question", value=f"{message}")
        emb.set_footer(text="Official GNAG Discord Bot Made by Lukeee#2222")
        msg = await ctx.channel.send(embed=emb)
    else:
          embed = discord.Embed(title="Permission Denied.",
                                description="You don't have permission to execute this command.",
                                color=0xff0000)
          embed.set_footer(text="Official GNAG Discord Bot Made by Lukeee#2222")
          await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    if em1:
        await msg.add_reaction(em1)
    if em2:
        await msg.add_reaction(em2)
    if em3:
        await msg.add_reaction(em3)
    else:
        print("only 2 emojis ig. :C")
    if em4:
        await msg.add_reaction(em4)
    else:
        print("Only 3 emojis ig. :C")
    if em5:
        await msg.add_reaction(em5)
    else:
        print("Only 4 emojis ig. :C")
    if em6:
        await msg.add_reaction(em6)
    else:
        print("Only 5 emojis ig. :C")
    if em7:
        await msg.add_reaction(em7)
    else:
        print("Only 6 emojis ig. :C")
    if em8:
        await msg.add_reaction(em8)
    else:
        print("Only 7 emojis ig. :C")
    if em9:
        await msg.add_reaction(em9)
    else:
        print("Only 8 emojis ig. :C")
    if em10:
        await msg.add_reaction(em10)
    else:
        print("Only 9 emojis ig. :C")```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> You can only have one keyword-only argument due to parsing ambiguities.

To simply fix your code delete the keyword-only argument (the `*`)

```py
async def poll(ctx, message, em1, em2, em3=None, em4=None, em5=None, em6=None, em7=None, em8=None, em9=None, em10=None):
```

Comment: If I do that, it works but then if I put a question that is more than one word such as "Cats or Dogs?" then put the emojis I want in the reaction like  , it is basically reading or and dogs as two separate emojis and no reactions pop up now. So now the command is `!poll Cats Or Dogs?  ` which now comes up with the error `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 10014): Unknown Emoji` because it thinks "Or Dogs" is an emoji.

Comment: Why don't you use converters? And why don't simply get the args as a list or emojis? What's the purpose of that whole thing? Also you can simply put a try/except block

Comment: @Luke put your question "in quotes, like this" and then it won't do that anymore. ``!poll "cats or dogs?" :dog: :cat:``

Comment: Thanks, didn't even realize that was a thing.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is keep this code then just put your question in quotes ex: !poll "Cats Or Dogs?" :dog: :cat: